# Generate URI for local file in Unix?

Tags: bash, unix

I have a lot of files for which I want to generate a URI. I am  looking for a command in unix which can do this.

Some of the files have special characters like spaces for which the URI should contain the appropriate symbol (like %20). Is there a command in unix to get the absolute URI for a local file. Something along the lines of

`geturi "file with spaces.pdf"`

which gives the output

`file:path/to/file/file%20with%20spaces.pdf`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only programming language that this question is tagged with is bash.  So here is a bash solution:

```
#!/bin/bash
fname=$(readlink -f "$1") # get full path
fname=${fname//%/%25}     # Substitute for percent signs
fname=${fname// /%20}     # Substitute for spaces
fname=${fname//+/%2B}     # Substitute for plus signs
echo "file:$fname"
```

In operation, it looks like:

```
$ geturi  file\ with\ spaces.pdf
file:/path/to/file/file%20with%20spaces.pdf
```

And,

```
$ bash geturi.sh file\ with\ spaces+%.pdf 
file:/path/to/file/file%20with%20spaces%2B%25.pdf
```

In the above code, each character that needs to be substituted requires a line like the one above for spaces.

For a small increase in complexity, however, we can get a much more general version:

```
#!/bin/bash
fname=$(readlink -f "$1")
nchars=${#fname}
encoded=""
for (( i=0 ; i<nchars ; i++ )); do
    c=${fname:$i:1}
    case "$c" in
        [-_.~a-zA-Z0-9/]) o="$c" ;;
        *)               printf -v o '%%%02x' "'$c"
    esac
    encoded+="$o"
done
echo "file:${encoded}"
```

The standard governing URI quoting is [RFC2396](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2396.txt). A good list of the problem characters and their substitutions is [here](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp).

Comment: exactly what I wanted. I did not consider other languages, but out of curiosity, is there a simpler way (in possibly another language?)

Comment: Good.  Languages like perl and python (see [urllib](http://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html)) come with library functions that do this.  If the above does what you want, though, there is no need to add the complication.

Answer (score 0):

According to the link [here](http://theunixshell.blogspot.com/search/label/rename):
This should work:

```
ls -1 $PWD/*.pdf| awk '{old=$0;gsub(/ /,"%20",$0);print "file:"$0}'
```